# An sql query to find users with common tags in a defined set

Tags: sql

```
amydeshane  0.180751    games
amydeshane  0.178772    video
```

I need a query that finds instances like this, where the user has more than 1 tag from a set.

for instance `where Category in ('games','video','flash')`

I want that the more tags that are in common with the set, the higher they are ranked. for instance 'amydeshane' should have `matching_terms = 2`

any ideas?

right now this is my query, but it is not giving me the results I need because I want that 'amydeshane' is ranked higher as it contains more tags matching

```
SELECT        TOP (10) Username, tfidf AS TotalUsed
FROM            UserInfo
WHERE        (Category IN ('video', 'graphics', 'editor', 'games', 'youtube'))
GROUP BY Username, tfidf
HAVING        (COUNT(Username) > 1)
ORDER BY TotalUsed DESC
```

These are the results:

```
kingjames23 0.626885
F_David 0.406635
bjhscomputers   0.401741
jaw6    0.347777
lkw5151604  0.257147
anniemalahus    0.242461
opusfluke   0.240047
pporto  0.235550
amydeshane  0.180751
amydeshane  0.178772
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select username, sum(tfidf) as totalused
from userinfo
where category in(...)
group by username
having count(category) > 1
order by sum(tfidf) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from your results that each of the other users only has 1 tag?

I'm not sure if it's what you want, but you could do a count on the username field and a sum on the totalused field...

```
SELECT TOP (10) Username, COUNT(Username) AS TagCount, SUM(tfidf) AS TotalUsed 
FROM UserInfo 
WHERE (Category IN ('video', 'graphics', 'editor', 'games', 'youtube')) 
GROUP BY Username, tfidf 
HAVING (COUNT(Username) > 1) 
ORDER BY COUNT(Username),TotalUsed DESC
```