# SQL find sets with common members (relational division)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, relational-division

I have separate sets of "classes" and "groups", each of which has been assigned one or more tags. I would like to find, for each group, the subset of classes that contains the same (or more) tags for each group.

Some sample data:

```
declare @Groups table
(
    GroupID int,
    TagID int
)

insert @Groups
values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
    (2,1),(2,2),
    (3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)

declare @Classes table
(
    ClassID int,
    TagID int
)

insert @Classes
values (1,1),(1,2),
    (2,1),(2,2),
    (3,1),(3,2),(3,3)

select * from @Groups
select * from @Classes
```

And output:

```
GroupID TagID
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
3       1
3       2
3       3
3       4

ClassID TagID
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
3       1
3       2
3       3
```

An example result set would look like this:

```
declare @Results table
(
    GroupID int,
    ClassID int
)

insert @Results
values (1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,null)

select * from @Results
```

Results output:

```
GroupID ClassID
1       3
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       NULL
```

I understand this is a relational division type problem, involving `having` and `count`. These posts describe what I want to do, but I can't figure out how to apply the examples to the particular case above:

- http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/07/02/Proper-Relational-Division-With-Sets.aspx
- [SQL Join only if all records have a match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142813/sql-join-only-if-all-records-have-a-match)
- [How can I structure a query to give me only the rows that match ALL values in a CSV list of IDs in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492699/how-can-i-structure-a-query-to-give-me-only-the-rows-that-match-all-values-in-a)
- [SQL: select sets containing exactly given members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776178/sql-select-sets-containing-exactly-given-members)
- [An sql query to find users with common tags in a defined set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070937/an-sql-query-to-find-users-with-common-tags-in-a-defined-set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should also work

```
select distinct g.GroupID, c.ClassID
from @Groups g
    left join @Classes c on g.TagID = c.TagID
where not exists (
    select *
    from @Groups g2
    where g2.GroupID = g.GroupID
        and g2.TagID not in (
            select TagID
            from @Classes c2
            where c2.ClassID = c.ClassID
        )
    ) or c.ClassID is null
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! and +1 for getting the double negation method right.  I would try to avoid this in production environments, because it can be quite baffling unless you are familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer for correctly returning null for empty groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the tables together, and demand that all tags from the group are found in the class:

```
select  g.GroupID
,       c.ClassID
from    @Groups g
join    @Classes c
on      c.TagID = g.TagID
group by
        g.GroupID
,       c.ClassID
having  count(c.TagID) =
        (
        select  count(*)
        from    @Groups g2
        where   g2.GroupID = g.GroupID
        )
```

This does not list groups without a matching class, and I can't think of a simple way to do so.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fff5/1/0)

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it does the job, away from test system right now but will confirm once fully tested.

Comment: "demand that all tags from the group are found in the class"... Thanks for the clear logic too, the subquery was the missing link for me.